# logstash with elasticsearch_http

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

Apparently logstash OnDemand account does not work when I wanted to post an issue.

Anyways, I have a logstash setup with redis, elasticsearch, and kibana. My logstash are collecting logs from several files and putting in redis just fine.

Logstash version 1.3.3
Elasticsearch version 1.0.1

The only thing I have in elasticsearch_http for logstash is the host name. This all setup seems to glue together just fine.

The problem is that the elasticsearch_http is not consuming the redis entries as they come. What I have seen by running it in debug mode is that it flush about 100 entries after every 1 min (flush_size and idle_flush_time's default values). The documentation however states, from what I understand is, that it will force a flush in case the 100 flush_size is not satisfied (for example we had 10 messages in last 1 min). But it seems to work the other way. Its flushing about 100 messages every 1 min only. I changed the size to 2000 and it flush 2000 every min or so.

Here is my `logstash-indexer.conf`

```
input {
 redis {
  host => "1xx.xxx.xxx.93"
  data_type => "list"
  key => "testlogs"
  codec => json
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch_http {
  host => "1xx.xxx.xxx.93"
 }
}
```

Here is my elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: logger
node.name: "logstash"
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["1xx.xxx.xxx.93:9300"]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.enabled: true
network.bind_host: 1xx.xxx.xxx.93
network.publish_host: 1xx.xxx.xxx.93
```

The `indexer`, `elasticsearch`, `redis`, and `kibana` are on same server. The log collection from file is done on another server.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to suggest a couple of different approaches to solve you problem. Logstash as you are discovering can be a bit quirky so I've found a these approaches useful in dealing with unexpected behavior from logstash.

1. Use the `elasticsearch` output instead of `elasticsearch_http`. You
   can get the same functionality by using `elasticsearch` output with
   protocol set to `http`. The `elasticsearch` output is more mature
   (milestone 2 vs milestone 3) and I've seen this change make a
   difference before.
2. Set the defaults for `idle_flush_time` and `flush_size`. There have
   been issues with Logstash defaults previously, I've found it to be a
   lot safer to set them explicitly. `idle_flush_time` is in seconds,
   `flush_size` is the number of records to flush.
3. Upgrade to more recent versions of logstash. There is
   enough of a change in how logstash is deployed with version 1.4.X
   (http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/release-notes) that I'd that I'd
   bite the bullet and upgrade. It's also significantly easier to get
   attention if you still have a problem with the most recent stable
   major release.
4. Make certain your Redis version matches those support by your
   logstash version.
5. Experiment with setting the batch, batch_events and batch_timeout
   values for the Redis output. You are using the `list` `data_type`.
   `list` supports various batch options and as with some other
   parameters it's best not to assume the defaults are always being set
   correctly.
6. Do all of the above. In addition to trying the first set of
   suggestions, I'd try all of them together in various combinations.
7. Keep careful records of each test run. Seems obvious but between all
   the variations above it's easy to lose track - I'd keep careful
   records and try to change only one variation at a time.